# Most performant protocol for uploading binary data to a jax-rs (REST) service

Tags: java, javascript, json, jax-rs

**Environment**

My application (war) has a JavaScript frontend and a Java REST service.

The files to be uploaded will be generated in the frontend, but not directly by user interaction -- this is *not* a use case where the user is uploading files herself. For that reason, it's necessary to initiate the upload from the JavaScript code.

I need to be able to send metadata (generated by other parts of the application) about the binary data when I'm uploading it -- which is why I need some sort of protocol instead of just uploading a file.

**Question**

What I haven't been able to determine is what the best practice is for uploading files, with regards, primarily, to the protocol used.

I've come across the following protocols:

- json
- xml
- proctol-buffers (via [protobuf.js](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-js))

However, the internets has, as usual, lots of different info that hasn't been giving me a coherent picture:

- With regards to reliability, the internets seems to say that you're better off using the `multipart/mixed` type to transfer data, instead of the pure `application/octet-stream` type.
- json doesn't natively doesn't support binary data, and apparently, Base64 has a high processing overhead.
- It's a JavaScript frontend, so json would be preferred.
- Sure, I could use protobuf.js, but I'd rather use leading-edge tech than bleeding-edge tech.

My priorities are:

- reliable data transfer of files between 1 and 10 megabytes.
- performant and efficient data transfer.
- readable code/architecture

In short, **which of the 3 formats mentioned above fits those requirements the best, given that I'm using a Java REST service on the backend?**

(If the fact that I'm using a Java REST service -- instead of say, a servlet -- to upload the files is going to be the biggest slowdown, that's also a good answer!)

**EDIT**: added information asked by the comments -- thanks!

Comment: Have you considered posting the files using html forms with `multipart/form-data` data content type? JAX-RS implementations support the type out of the box and it sounds like an easy solution to leave the rest to the browser. There would be no need to do it on your own in JavaScript.

Comment: "JavaScript front end" ... you mean that the user interface is a web page (with some JavaScript), right?  If not, you should clarify. Generally people do file uploads via HTML forms and "file" `<input>` elements. Those have been supported by web browsers for a very long time, and allow for the uploading of arbitrary files. You should also describe how you need to get this metadata about the files.